# How to set time to Zeros in DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

Lets say I have the following DateTime variable

```
DateTime CurDate = '26/3/2014 12:00:00 AM';
```

I'm wondering how can I set the `CurDate` so that the value will become `26/3/2014 00:00:00 AM`

Note that I still want the time, but with all zeros.

**P/S: The reason for having all zeros is because the datetime value stored in SQL Server is `26/3/2014 00:00:00.000`. I need to cast `CurDate` to have all zeros in order to match database data

Comment: This is really a formatting problem. `12:00:00 AM` == `00:00:00` in 24-hour format. There is no such thing as `00:00:00 AM`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is most certainly an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/201534).  Instead of asking about a problem with your proposed solution, consider asking about the original problem instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use

```
CurDate.Date and that will give you '26/3/2012 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to format DateTime:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 06, 21, 0, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"));
```

Result:

```
21.06.2014 00:00:00
```

More informations:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
// Parse the string you have, to create a datetime.
DateTime CurDate = DateTime.ParseExact('26/3/2014 12:00:00 AM', 
                                       "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// Create the datetime you want based on the CurDate
DateTime result = new DateTime(CurDate.Year, CurDate.Month, CurDate.Day, 0, 0, 0);
```

For more information about `ParseExact` please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere, in `SQL Server` or in `.NET` dates hasn't any presentation. They are just an numeric value. Don't care about that, both the `SQL Server` and `.NET` so smart that can pass parameters without any confusion. Just pass parameters of the correct data type.

Answer (score 1):

Use 24 Hour Format

```
DateTime CurDate = DateTime.Parse("3/26/2014 12:00:00 AM");
Console.WriteLine("12 Hour Format: " + CurDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
Console.WriteLine("24 Hour Format: " + CurDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but I think this was the proper answer for future references:

```
Console.WriteLine("Current Date with 0s on time part: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        this.dtGelisSaati = DateTime.Now;
```

set curency time values

```
        this.dtGelisSaati = DateTime.Today;
```

this ok. zero time values set.

Answer (score 0):

Put .Date and get the date part with zero time part.
I use Linq as:

var list = Results.Where(x => x.ExpDate.Date >= From.Date && x.ExpDate.Date <= To.Date).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

CurDate = new DateTime(CurDate.Year, CurDate.Month, CurDate.Day, 0, 0, 0);